# I got an error while creating react app that says -g is not recognize but i installed npm node latest versions

Tags: reactjs, node.js, create-react-app, coder

C:\Users\kanse>npx create-react-app first-app
'CALL "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.1